# C++ HANA сгенерировать JSON

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Как дополнить этот код, чтобы вместо вывода значений полей выводился, например, json вида:

```
'{"name":"John", "age":30}'



#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

struct Person
{
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
        (std::string, name),
        (int, age)
    );
};


int main()
{
    namespace hana = boost::hana;

    auto serialize = [](std::ostream& os, const auto& object) {
        hana::for_each(hana::members(object), [&](auto member) {
            os << member << std::endl;
        });
    };

    Person john{"John", 30};
    serialize(std::cout, john);

    return 0;
}
```

Не знаю, как при помощи ханы получить названия полей, в документации нет таких примеров.

Моя попытка не компилируется:

```
auto serialize2 = [](std::ostream& os, const auto& object) -> std::string {
    std::string json = "{";
    hana::for_each(object, [&json](auto pair) {
        json += "\"" + hana::to<const char *>(hana::first(pair)) + "\":\"" + hana::second(pair) + "\"";
    });
    json += "}";
    os << json;
    return json;
};
```

error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char[2]' and 'const char *')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имена полей вы получаете правильно.

Сообщение об ошибке, связано с вычислением выражения: `"\"" + hana::to<const char *>(hana::first(pair))` :
Старые C-e строки (`const char*`) не поддерживают сложение строк. Чтобы сложение работало, нужно чтобы хотя бы один из аргументов был C++ строкой (std::string).

Вот пример (требует еще большой доработки напильником):
https://godbolt.org/z/jh66rsqEa

```
std::string serialize_json(const auto& object)
{
    namespace hana = boost::hana;
    std::string json = "{";
    hana::for_each(object, [&json](auto pair) {
       // Убрал оборачивание имени поля в кавычки, поскольку ключом может быть не только строка.
        json += serialize_json(hana::to<const char *>(hana::first(pair))); 
        json += ":";
       // Числа, массивы, дочерние структуры, тоже ненужно брать в кавычки.
       // Будут ли обрамляющие кавычки - зависит от типа данных.
        json += serialize_json(hana::second(pair));
        json += ",";
    });
    if(json.back() ==',') // После последнего элемента, запятой быть не должно.
        json.resize( json.size()-1 );
    json += "}";
    //os << json;
    return json;

};
```

Наверное есть и другие подводные камни, которые я не учел.